# Apollo Subscription using "apollo-server-azure-functions"

Tags: node.js, graphql, azure-functions, graphql-subscriptions

I am using "apollo-server-azure-functions" npm package using this can we implement graphql subscriptions. I checked above npm package repos in the github but i did not find option for Subscriptions

Comment: Check if this helps: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/deployment/azure-functions/ Also please elaborate your question with right set of example scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. This isn't supported.

Also, Azure Functions themselves do not support websockets directly. Instead, you will have to use another service like [Azure SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-overview).